# CMake: target_link_libraries based on flag

Tags: cmake, cmakelists-options, target-link-libraries

There are 4 libs linked already and want to link a new library if FLAG is ON.

```
target_link_libraries (lib1 lib2 lib3 lib4 ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})
```

I want it to be something like

```
target_link_libraries (lib1 lib2 lib3 lib4 if(FLAG) lib5 endif() ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})
```

Is there anyway to implement this in cmakelists.txt?

Comment: You may **conditionally** (under `if` command) set a variable and (unconditionally) pass this variable to the `target_link_libraries` call. See e.g. that question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41572275/3440745. Alternatively, you could **conditionally** call `target_link_libraries(lib1 lib5)`.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use multiple `target_link_library` commands.

E.g. the following could be used to add a lib for unix targets

```
target_link_libraries (lib1 lib2 lib3 lib4 ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})

if(UNIX)
    target_link_libraries(lib1 lib5)
endif()
```

Alternatively you could use a list containing the libs to include

```
set(LIBS lib2 lib3 lib4 ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})

if(UNIX)
    list(APPEND LIBS lib5)
endif()

target_link_libraries(lib1 ${LIBS})
```

In theory you could also use generator expressions, but imho this would make for the least readable alternative

```
target_link_libraries(lib1 lib2 lib3 lib4 ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS} $<$<BOOL:${UNIX}>:lib5>)
```